# Ruby class << self variable, accessing from another class

Tags: ruby, class

I'm having a trouble figuring out how to access a variable in a `class << self` from another class. I've searched and found many questions close to this but not exactly:

```
class << self
  @@var="foo"
end

class A
  puts @@var
end
```

I've even tried creating class `A` within `class << self` with no luck either.
How can I access `@@var`?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). You haven't really given us enough context to understand what problem you're actually trying to solve. Please help us understand the big picture, and show us the actual code you're trying to make work. (Incidentally, your example code works just fine entered directly into `irb` (Ruby 1.9.2), further proof that we need *real* code to help you solve your actual problem.)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
class << self
  @@var="foo"
end

self.class.class_variable_get :@@var
```

But I'm really skeptical that you actually need to use a class variable in a singleton class.  It seems complicated.  Maybe you could ask another question explaining what you're really trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for my last post... still learning how to use the site. But yes you're both right that what I'm trying to do is more complex but I was trying to simplify the question. Especially since I'm a newb to rubuy, classes and programming in general. :) What I'm actually doing is writting a plugin for Sketchup, and the code I have to begin with resides in class << self and I'm adding a new class called class Tool and I need to access  some variables that reside inside class << self. I hope that helps.